# Can you have multiple custom Login Forms with unique templates Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

I want to use our Joomla 3.x site to do three different functions and therefore have three templates and I have setup three menus, but assigned more than one login form doesn't seem to work. It just picks one even if both are enabled. Using custom overrides on the templates doesn't help either. Will I need to setup multiple Joomlas? Basicly I want the login form to have the template of the section of the website it's logging into but I can't seem to be able to do that!
Thanks
Paul

Maybe I can explain it another way! We have direct clients who we want to have access to protected files and would use the main website. We have something like Shop managers who we would point to a different url and have a different theme/template and be able to login to access sales material and we have a webapp which either can login and access that webapp. At the moment from our current site I'm using an iframe to a joomla site and using the joomla users to allow access to that system, so it doesn't have any template or in fact is a blank template. So if the user accesses any of these hidden menus and isn't logged in I would like them to go to 3 different styles of login form. Maybe I can disable the login 'form'? and if not loged in ask them to use the login module that's already on the page?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am confused about what you are asking - you want to assign three different login modules to three different templates?,

If so, you could create three login modules for each template, and then use [Advanced Module Manager](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager) to assign the login modules to each specific template.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you want to do and its purpose, but if I understood at some level your question, you could use a 3rd party form extension, that can integrate with the Joomla User (e.g. RS Forms) and set up 3 different forms according to your needs. You can create then 3 different menu-items for these 3 forms.

If you don't need to have different functionality in each form, you could just create one, and use it as module or inside an article through a content plugin, for all of the 3 different menu-items.

Hope this helps a bit...